# Flash builder: datagrid remove item - index out of bound

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid, air, builder, removechild

I have an issue which i can't solve at the moment, a little help would be much appreciated.
A local XML file is loaded into a HTTPservice and load the data into a DataGrid. The local file contains information about locally stored files.

Just to be secure and sure, when the AIR app loads, i want to run through the loaded datagrid and check if the local file exists. If it doesn't exist, i want to delete the row in the datagrid.

Doing that i get this annoying error: The supplied index is out of bounds.

I know that, deleting an element in the datagrid will result in new indexes which causes this error.

Thanks for your advice!

```
public function checkiffileislocal(event:Event):void{

            var i:int;
            var count:Number = (dgUserRequest.dataProvider as ICollectionView).length;

            for (i=0;i < count;i++)
            {

                dgUserRequest.selectedIndex = i;
                if (File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath(dgUserRequest.selectedItem.id).exists == false)
                {   
                    dgUserRequest.removeChildAt(dgUserRequest.selectedIndex);
                }

            }


        }
```

Comment: Typically when you iterate over something with the intent of removing items, you want to do that iteration backwards. Otherwise you loop code may end up producing errors like this. With that said, the answer below is also appropriate. Delete items from the dataProvider (rather than removing child objects). If you want to disable rows, you could add a "isDisabled" property to each item so that the item renderer can use this to show the row in a disabled state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds to me like you want to delete an item from the dataProvider; not a visual child of a DataGrid.

The rows of a DataGrid are not its children.

The rows/columns are created automatically based on the number of items in the dataProvider.  You should not be trying to manipulate the rows / column objects directly.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Disabling a row is also an option. Any way to do that?

Comment: @webgeek I think you need to read up on renderer recycling.  Assuming your grid has scrollbars; there is no way to guarantee that a certain row will only be displaying a certain set of data.  I cannot envision a use case where it makes sense to disable a row given those constraints.  Because as the user scrolls that row will display different data.  I wonder if you need a custom itemRenderer that will disable the cell based on the data.  That way as the user scrolls through the grid the cell will remain disabled.